# Let $G$ be a nonabelian group with $|G|=p^3$. Show $Z(G)=G'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a nonabelian group with $|G|=p^3$. Show $Z(G)=G'$.

What I know so far:

$Z(G) \neq 1$ because $G$ is a p-group.

$Z(G) \neq G$ because $G$ is nonabelian

$G' \neq 1$ because $G$ is nonabelian.

So $|Z(G)| \in \{p,p^2\}$

But also $|Z(G)| \neq p^2$, because if it did then $\frac{G}{Z(G)} \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, so $G$ would be abelian.

Thus $|Z(G)|=p$

Now, if I can somehow show that $|G'| = p$ then I will be done, but alas, I have come to and impass and would like some help from y'all!!!

Comment: If $|G'|=p^2$, then $G/G'$ is cyclic. This implies $G$ is abelian. Try to prove this statement.

Comment: Okay, Thanks, I will. How do I know that $|G'| \neq p^3$?

Comment: A solvable-group has nontrivial abelianization, and you know finite $p$-groups are solvable..

Comment: Okay, where $alb(G)=\frac{G}{G'}$? So if $alb(G) = 1$ then $G'=G$. But since $alb(G) \neq 1$, we have that $|G'| \neq p^3$

Comment: I made a great mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another approach.

We know $G/Z(G)$ has order $p^2$ so is abelian.  Since $G'$ is the smallest normal subgroup such that $G/G'$ is abelian, we have $G'\leq Z(G)$.  However, $G'\neq 1$ and $Z(G)$ has order $p$, so we must have $G'=Z(G)$.